# Is there any possibility to insert bulk of records with in second in database in android?

Tags: android, insert, bulk

I want to insert 400 questions into database with in a second. Please let me know if any one knows the example or answer. Your help is much needed and appreciated. Thanks in advance....

Thank you,
Krishna

Answer (score 1):

Use a compiled statement.

[How do I use prepared statements in SQlite in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android)

There's a helper class in android that you can use to make things a bit easier also. It's [DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html) and here is a [good tutorial on how to use it](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/).

Answer (score 0):

Insert into the database in separate thread. Use prepared statements.