# SQLite Update problem in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have tried to browse it here, but i couldn't find a solution. The problem is,

I have a database, and i want to update a column in the database, such that the updated value is 1 less than the previous..
Basically, in SQL, it UPDATE TABLE TNAME SET VAL=VAL-1 where

How do i do that in Android?
I tried doing this

```
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
args.put(KEY_ROWID, "KEY_ROWID-1");
db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + ">0", null);
```

But this doesn't work.

I will be thankful if you can help me with this!

Nithin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a working SQL-syntax, there is no need to "build" it in Android. You can for example use a [PreparedStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) (which accepts an SQL-String) and use your Query there.

A nice example can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android/436162#436162).

Answer (score 2):

```
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("UPDATE TABLE TNAME SET VAL=VAL-1");
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: I tried, it says "SQLiteStatement" cannot be resolved to a type! I don't understand why it says this