# Updating table not working properly

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to use following code, but I am unable to update my table.

```
db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
int i = 1;
String updateStatement = "update "+MESSAGE_TABLE+" SET status ="+i+" where message_id = "+message_id;
SQLiteStatement update;
update = db.compileStatement(updateStatement);
update.executeInsert();
```

Instead of `update.executeInsert()`, I also tried `update.executeI()`, but it did not work either.

Comment: If you attach a logcat output of the error it will help others diagnose your problem

Comment: In log cat it is showing the data is updated. but when i retrieve data from table... the data is not updated

Comment: Are you sure the return value of executeUpdateDelete() is 1?

Comment: I haven't use `executeUpdateDelete()`. But Right I got my solution... Thanks for the support. if possible please give me link which have example of this command `executeUpdateDelete()` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);    

ContentView update = new ContentView();
update.put("fieldNameToUpdate","Value Here as a String " or integer);
db.update("table", update,/*where clause*/ "id=2",null);

db.close();
```

This works for me. 
you can change the values as per your requirement.

Thanks
sHaH..

Answer (score 1):

Use `executeUpdateDelete()` method in `SQLiteStatement` and read docs well. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [SQLiteStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html) with the `executeUpdateDelete()` method, this works:

```
String sql = "UPDATE table_name SET column_2=? WHERE column_1=?";
SQLiteStatement statement = db.compileStatement(sql);

int id = 7;
String stringValue = "hi there";

statement.bindString(1, stringValue);
statement.bindLong(2, id); // These match to the two question marks in the sql string

int numberOfRowsAffected = statement.executeUpdateDelete();
```

Note: `executeUpdateDelete()` was introduced in API 11. [See this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13365558/sqlitestatement-execute-a-select-insert-delete-update).

[Fuller explanation on how to use prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29797229/3681880):

Answer (score 0):

look here
http://www.higherpass.com/Android/Tutorials/Accessing-Data-With-Android-Cursors/

Answer (score 0):

I think if every other thing is right problem is in your query

problem may be in the field type.Suppose if message_id is not a number.Then use like

```
 String updateStatement = "update "+MESSAGE_TABLE+" SET status ="+i+" where message_id = '"+message_id+"'";
```

Same for the fields status if it is not a number type have to use ''