# Android SQLite: Which query ("query" or "rawQuery") is faster?

Tags: android, database

I am developing one android database application . I just want to know which code execute faster and what is the difference between them?

**Query - 1** =

```
db.rawQuery("select * from user_table where user_id =" + userId, null);
```

**Query - 2** =

```
db.query(USER_TABLE_NAME, ALL_COLUMNS, "user_id = " + userId, null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: ...try it and see? I'm going to guess "the same" for all intents and purposes. But, *please use placeholders in either case*.

Comment: If you have a build system already set up, do some benchmarks on it. Also, what kind of workload are you expecting and what margins in speed are you looking for?

Answer (score 18):

Use query.

Android precompile queries and using too many different raw queries may cause performance issue.

Use rawQuery only when absolutely needed.

Also, both your example have a MAJOR security issue of SQL Injection.

You should sanitize the userId.

The most obvious thing to do is let Android do it by using:

```
db.query(USER_TABLE_NAME, ALL_COLUMNS, "user_id = ?", new String[] {userId}, null, null, null);
```

Comment: RE precompiled queries: Those only apply when using PreparedStatement. Query() just builds the string and passes it to rawQuery().

Comment: Well, PreparedStatement are meant to run the same query multiple time, true, but I think some kind of optimization is also performed by the driver. I've encountered some error when using multiple different queries of android complaining too many statement was provided. :)

Comment: @JonAdams Please help me understand your comment, 'only apply when using preparedstatement', where do we use preparedstatement while same can be achieved by rawQuery? (ie you can put '?' , and pass arguments?)

Comment: @Darpan Yes, you can still put parameters in all query types. I was just clarifying that the parts about performance in this answer weren't quite correct.

Comment: @Darpan, more info about prepared statements: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29797229/3681880

Comment: Thank you @Suragch :) this explain what I was referring to talking about performance far better then how I could explain myself

Comment: I realize I'm digging up an old thread here, but how is Android automatically sanitizing user_ind in your code? Does this argument in the query() method automatically get sanitized?

Comment: if you use the ? + parameters it just sql escape the parameters

Comment: by the way, stumbling here after a lot of time and rereading the comments. @JonAdams was right, precompiled queries only apply to `PreparedStatements`. Query DOES build the query string and execute raw string looking at the code. But I remember stumbling on some kind of error, using `query()` when i used too many different queries string and so I went for the assumption that the framework was performing some kind of optimization. I don't know for sure but I think it would make sense if it has it.

Comment: Regardless the performance difference between building the query string and not building it is negligible compared to the actual query so I would still advice for using the cleaner API, the `query()` unless you need to build the raw query programmatically. And definally use positional parameters! (`?`) to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 8):

Looking at SQLiteDatabase.java in the android source shows that the query(..) ends up calling the QueryBuilder to build the query as a single string and then it essentially calls rawQuery(). They should be roughly equivalent, assuming that you also did the same work to build your own statement.