# Android: Inserting batch data (one time) using SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

below is the code, currently i am using, but i am looking a way to speed up my insert and i have 100+ rows inserted on very first time... any thoughts?

```
public class SQLiteAdapter {

private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private Context context;

public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
    context = c;
}

   public long insert(String empId, String name......)
   {
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
      contentValues.put(KEY_EMP_ID, empId);
      .....................
      .....................
      .....................
      return sqLiteDatabase.insert(KEY_TABLE, null, contentValues); 
   }


   public void InsertReciters()
   {
     //currently, this is how i am doing, how can i speed up inserting the rows in to db?
    //i have 100+ rows ..........

     this.insert("ac123", ................);
     this.insert("ac133", ................);
     this.insert("ac143", ................);
     this.insert("ac153", ................);
     this.insert("ac163", ................);
     .................
     ................. 
   }  
}
```

Comment: You can use pre-populated database: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9109728/265167

Comment: prepared statements and transactions: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29797229/3681880

Answer (score 3):

Suggest you insert huge data by transaction.

See below code format:

```
List<String[]> hugeData=new ArrayList<String[]>();
try{
   sqLiteDatabase.beginTransaction();
    //insert huge data
    //get pre-compiled SQLiteStatement object
    SQLiteStatement statement=sqLiteDatabase.compileStatement("insert into tablename(..) value (?,?)")   
    for(String[] row:hugeData){
      statement.bindString(1,row[0]);
      //......
      statement.execute();
    }
   sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
}finally{
  sqLiteDatabase..endTransaction();
}
```

---------------------edited------------------

```
public class SQLiteAdapter {

private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
private Context context;
List<String[]> insertData=null;

public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
    context = c;
}
 public SQLiteAdapter(Context c,List<String[]> _insertData){
    this(c);
    insertData=_insertData;
}
   public long insert(String empId, String name......)
   {
      ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
      contentValues.put(KEY_EMP_ID, empId);
      .....................
      .....................
      .....................
      return sqLiteDatabase.insert(KEY_TABLE, null, contentValues); 
   }


   public void InsertReciters()
   {
     //currently, this is how i am doing, how can i speed up inserting the rows in to db?
    //i have 100+ rows ..........

     this.insert("ac123", ................);
     this.insert("ac133", ................);
     this.insert("ac143", ................);
     this.insert("ac153", ................);
     this.insert("ac163", ................);
     .................
     ................. 
   }  

  public void InsertBatchData()
   {
    try{
   sqLiteDatabase.beginTransaction();
    //insert huge data
    //get pre-compiled SQLiteStatement object
    SQLiteStatement statement=sqLiteDatabase.compileStatement("insert into tablename(..) value (?,?)")   
    for(String[] row:hugeData){
      statement.bindString(1,row[0]);
      //......
      statement.execute();
    }
   sqLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful();
   }finally{
    sqLiteDatabase..endTransaction();
   }
   }
}
```

Comment: i dont understand the `....compileStatement("insert....` i have like 100+ rows ...

Comment: That return pre-compiled SQLiteStatement object. This object can then be used to efficiently execute this statement multiple times.

Comment: okay so i am confused in the `value` what do you want me to defined enter the values for the row and then in the for loop statement? can you use my code to demonstrate... may be i am bit confused with the way you used your insert statement.

Comment: First, if you want to insert huge data, you must have the huge data object that will insert database. May be you can use List<String[]> type object to store huge data. Your can loop List<String[]> object to insert data.