# sqlite query runtime error

Tags: android, sqlite, compiler-errors, runtime

I was working with sqlite but I end up with this error.I'm not getting what is error here.

Below is my logcat.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "/": syntax error: , while compiling: 

SELECT start,end FROM crop_list WHERE name =/sdcard/Shri Ramachandra kripalu bhajamana.mp3
```

Comment: Probably add quotes around the value of `name` in your query.

Comment: I tried adding quotes but its the same error I'm getting

Comment: Use prepared statements instead of manually creating (incorrect) SQL statements: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is you forget to add the quotes marks (' ') like:

> SELECT start,end FROM crop_list WHERE name ='/sdcard/Shri Ramachandra kripalu bhajamana.mp3'.

Answer (score 0):

why do you not use class helper and Helper.dabase.query(.....) <- it is faster ;) around 2 segons faster that helper.dabase.rawquery ;)
[SQLiteOpenHelper | Android Developers](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html&ei=hWmVT-bIMaXW0QXW4_D8AQ&usg=AFQjCNEBb8YvlGxrEdTTNAan7LjslOLlYQ&sig2=3CZGyukB_mcBe5doXDhOQA) <-- best practice