# SQLite rawQuery selectionArgs and Integers Fields

Tags: android, sqlite

As the Android documents says, the selectionArgs parameters of the rawQuery method is parsed as strings.

> SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(String sql, String[] selectionArgs)
>
> selectionArgs: You may include ?s in where clause in the query,
> which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs.
> The values will be bound as Strings.

But today, I was faced with a problem that took a great part of my day. Imagine the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE IFNULL(COLUMN_A, 0) >= 15
```

COLUMN_A is INTEGER. The table has about 10 rows that attends to that criteria. Running the query on a database editor, the result was always correct, but, on the smartphone, the statement always returned no rows.

After some time, a changed the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE IFNULL(COLUMN_A, 0) >= '15'
```

and the editor returned no rows, just like Android. So, changing the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE CAST(IFNULL(COLUMN_A, 0) as INTEGER) >= '15'
```

solved the problem. Another test that was done was:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE COLUMN_A >= '15'
```

also, returned the correct result.

This appears to be a problem that involves the way that Android bounds the parameters to the query (as strings) with the IFNULL clause.

So, does anybody knows why this happened? Are there any suggestions to solve this without using CAST on the query?

Comment: I had the similar problem and I spent an hour trying to find an error in my app. Then I've found your post. Thus it's really great you wrote it here. Another thing is I will never understand Android philosopy and why this CAST is a must here....

Answer (score 11):

The reason why you *bind* your values to the query is to prevent an [SQL-injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

*Basically*, you send your query (including placeholders) to your database and say "My next query is going to be of this form and none other!". When an attacker then injects a different query-string (through a form-field, for example) the database says "Hey, that's not the query you said you would send!" and throws an error at you.

> <strike>Since commands (which can be injected into your actual query as show in the linked article) are strings, the string-datatype is the more "dangerous" one.
>   If a user tries to inject some code into your field which should only take numbers and you try to cast/parse the input to an integer (before putting the value into your query), you'll get an exception right away. With a string, there is no such kind security. Therefor, they have to be escaped probably.
>   That *might* be the reason that the bind values are all interpreted as strings.</strike>

The above is **bogus**! It doesn't matter if the arguments you bind are strings or integers, they're all equally dangerous. Also, pre-checking your values in-code results in a lot of boilerplate code, is error-prone and unflexible!

---

To prevent your application from SQL-Injections and also speed up multiple database **writing** operations (using the same query with different values), you should use "prepared statements". The correct class for **writing** to the database in the Android SDK is [`SQLiteStatement`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteStatement.html).

To create a prepared statement, you use the [`compileStatement()`-method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#compileStatement%28java.lang.String%29) of your `SQLiteDatabase`-object and bind the corresponding values (which will be replaced with the `?`-marks in your query) using the correct `bindXX()`-method (which are inherited from [`SQLiteProgram`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteProgram.html)):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO SomeTable (name, age) values (?,?)");
// Careful! The index begins at 1, not 0 !!
stmt.bindString(1, "Jon");
stmt.bindLong(2, 48L);
stmt.execute();
// Also important! Clean up after yourself.
stmt.close();
```

Example taken from this older question: [How do I use prepared statements in SQlite in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392)

---

Sadly, `SQLiteStatement` does not have an overload that returns a `Cursor`, so you can't use it for `SELECT`-statements. For those, you can use the `rawQuery(String, String[])`-method of `SQLiteDatabase`:

```
int number = getNumberFromUser();
String[] arguments = new String[]{String.valueOf(number)};
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE IFNULL(COLUMN_A, 0) >= ?", arguments);
```

Note that the `rawQuery()`-method takes a String-array for the argument values. This actually doesn't matter, SQLite will automatically convert to the correct type. As long as the string-representations equal what you would expect in an SQL query, you're fine.

Comment: Hi @lukas. Thanks to your response but, as said in the docs, prepared statements can't be used to return cursors.

Comment: @regisxp I don't know why I didn't see that. I updated my answer. Check it out.

Comment: Why is Android casting integers to `String`? You can't inject SQL queries with numbers, right? I wish the `selectionArguments` parameters was an array of `Object` and that the framework would keep integers as integers, and protect `String` from injections.

Comment: Android sqlite needs to change this, parameters should be Object like JDBC. String is not working for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50310213/android-sqlite-string-parameter-value-not-working?noredirect=1#comment87636468_50310213

Comment: @Sunnyday this should work regardless if you use `bindLong()`, like in the example above. You might also want to use [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room), the new official ORM for Android SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem I guess. The thing that you are trying to mention is that you can't make actual calculations regarding sqlite database. I have found out that the problem is bigger than the one that you mention. SQLite Database does not seem to understand any field types regarding the field value. Meaning that if you are trying to insert a String value in an INTEGER field type the insertion would not complain.

So the problem is even bigger as you can see. Although I have seen that if you have a column that has only Integers and you make a where statement like: where id = 1 without ' ' then there is a result dataset. So I might ask you if you are sure that this statement does not work: "SELECT * FROM TABLE_A WHERE IFNULL(COLUMN_A, 0) >= 15". But the where id >= '15' does work because it takes the string representation of id which is actual 2 unicode characters(!!!) and tries to make an operator >= to '15' which DOES apply.

The first time I came across these issues surprised me and I have decided to dynamically create the SQL  without binding parameters and executing as a whole String. I know it isn't the best way to access the database, without binding parameters, but it is a solution and a good one because security reasons are not that important though your database is secured and your methods of accessing it are private to your Application. If the "intruder" has the ability to access the database by a root phone he could just put it in an SQLITE Studio and he is done.

Comment: Hi @10s. Thanks for your comment. The 'first version' of my app used the same technic you said, replacing the parameters manually. I decided to change because some alerts I received from the OS, asking me to use arguments on queries to improve SQLite statement cache. Did you received this advices too?

Comment: No, luckily or not I haven't come across that kind of alerts yet and I am working on a business application that requires a lot of manually replacing SQL parameters with very "heavy" querries and joins, subqueries etc. So I guess I have tested to the full the SQLite capabilities in android. Can you please post these alerts in order to give me a hint?