# Android Sqlite delete statement unable to pass long parameter

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQLite rawQuery selectionArgs and Integers Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320434/sqlite-rawquery-selectionargs-and-integers-fields)

Here is my table schema

```
create table Account (accountId) // accountId is long in practice
```

I am not able to use the parameter version of delete to delete a row given an long id.  getPk() below returns a long id.

```
getDb().delete("Account", "accountId = ?", new String[]{ account.getPk().toString()});
```

However, I can workaround this by passing the parameter in the where clause.

```
getDb().delete("Account", "accountId = " + account.getPk().toString(), null);
```

My guess is that the parameter version of delete will work for string parameter but not integer/long parameter.  Any insight?

**EDIT:**
Another strange thing is, if I changed the table schema to below, both versions of delete work fine.

```
create table Account (accountId integer primary key autoincrement)
```

Comment: It's quite commonly confusing people...

Comment: As i remember in android SQLite, it's internal implementation is a lil tricky i would say, even though they ask our preference as to what we want to define a column as, like int, text date boolean etc... but end of the day, it's jus a preference, it will not be used to when they store our data. So whatever type we choose our attributes to be, internally everything is basically a string representation.  "The important idea here is that the type is recommended, not required." Check out the Type Affinity section in this link (http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

Comment: @PokerIncome.com i guess that's because you hinted the type and Android/SQLite is able to converted it internally.