# Android Sqlite query returning null

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a static sqlite database in Android.  A function takes a int type of input and makes a query to the database.  It's working fine upto input values of 97,500, but if I enter anything larger then one of two cases happens

1. If input is 98,000-99,500 it returns null
2. If input greater than 100,000 it returns the wrong data

Here's the function that's malfunctioning:

```
    Budget getBudget(int income,String name)
{
    Budget B=null;
    Log.d("DB", String.valueOf(income));
    try{
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+BudgetTable+" WHERE "+Low+"<=? AND "+High+">=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(income),String.valueOf(income)});
        Log.d("DB", String.valueOf(cur.getCount()));
        if(cur.getCount()!=0)
        {
            Log.d("DB", "Cursor not empty");
            cur.moveToFirst();
            B=new Budget(0, income,cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(MortgageRent)),cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Utilities)) , 
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(LightnPower)), cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(PhonenInternet)), 
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(HomeMaintenance)), cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(HomeCleaning)), 
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Groceries)), cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Clothing)),0, 
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(PersonalGrooming)), cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(MedicalnPharmacy)), 
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(HealthInsurance)), cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(LifeInsurance)), 
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(HomeInsurance)), cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Accounting)), 
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(BankFees)), cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Fuel)), 
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(ServicenRepairs)), cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(GovernmentCharges)), 
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(CarInsurance)),0, cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(PublicTransport)), 
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Entertainment)), cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(SportsnGym)),
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(EatOut)), cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Alcohol)), 
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Gifts)), cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Holidays)), 
                    cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(NewspapernMagazine)), cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(Others)), 0, 0, name);

            Log.d("DB", String.valueOf(cur.getInt(cur.getColumnIndex(IncomeLevel))));
            cur.close();
            db.close();

        }
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Log.d("DB", ex.getMessage());
    }
    return B;
}
```

Below is a screenshot of the data in database...I can't figure out why it doesn't work.
[image: Here's a screenshot of the data in database]

Answer (score 0):

As I can't see your database, I am led to believe the source of your problem is this line:

```
Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+BudgetTable+" WHERE "+Low+"<=? AND "+High+">=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(income),String.valueOf(income)});
```

specifically the fact that you are using `income` for both greater-equal than AND less than-equal. Are you sure this is what you want? Are you sure it is not cuppose to be

```
Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+BudgetTable+" WHERE "+Low+"<=? AND "+High+">=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(lowIncome),String.valueOf(highIncome)});
```

Comment: No the query is what I want and returning correct data for inputs less than 98000. I've attached a screenshot of the database too. See if income=98500 then rowid=17 should be selected which have low=97500 and high=102500 which evidently validates 97500<=98500 and 102500>=98500. But its returning null.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't pass numbers as strings, because strings have different rules of comparison, for example, the string "2000" will be considered greater than the string "102500".

They warn about it in the javadoc documentation:

> selectionArgs  You may include ?s in where clause in the query, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs. The values will be bound as Strings.

Your should rewrite your query like this:

```
Cursor cur=db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+BudgetTable+
                      " WHERE "+Low+"<=" + income + " AND "+High+">=" + income);
```

Also, it is quite a common issue and some people encountered a similar problem: [SQLite rawQuery selectionArgs and Integers Fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11320434/sqlite-rawquery-selectionargs-and-integers-fields)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've re-written the query as you said but now its always returning null.

Comment: @Mehedi Post a code that creates BudgetTable. I need to verify that some fields have the integer type.

Comment: Its solved, the issue was pretty silly...when I imported the data from a csv to the static database some fields got corrupted and those were creating the error...I have fixed the csv and imported data again and everything is working fine. Thanks for all your help.