# android sqlite string parameter value not working

Tags: android, sqlite, parameters, android-sqlite

Android sqlite string parameter value not working. For example,

```
SELECT t0.id FROM Employer t0 
WHERE (select count(t1.id) from Employee t1 where t1.employerId=t0.id) > ?
```

The parameter(?) value is a Number. Android sqlite needs parameter values to be 
String.

```
rawQuery(sql, String[] arguments)
```

From sqlite3 console:

If passing the parameter value as string such as "1", the query will always return empty set.

```
SELECT t0.id FROM Employer t0 
WHERE (select count(t1.id) from Employee t1 where t1.employerId=t0.id) > '1'
```

If It is a number such as 1:

```
SELECT t0.id FROM Employer t0 
WHERE (select count(t1.id) from Employee t1 where t1.employerId=t0.id) > 1
```

Works.

how to pass the number as a parameter value for the example above?

Comment: Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11320788/1797950) that may help you

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately compiled statement is not for query(select).

Comment: Build your raw query with your parameters set and pass null for arguments. You can use String.format() to build your query.

Comment: This is just a simple example. Same issues will go with other object types. Android sqlite really need to allow object type as parameter values like JDBC.