# Android Sqlite selection args[] incorrect value?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have different variants of a query. All value types are Strings! (don't ask why...)
The first one might look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE arg1=false
```

The string ("sqlWhere") for the arg(s) looks like this:
"arg1=?"

The string for the arg(s)-Array (args) at index 0 looks like this:
"false"

This works fine. I've got 715 results.

Now, if i have something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE (arg1=40 OR arg2=42) AND arg3=false
```

I'll expect 110 results for this. But there aren't any results, no Exception is thrown

If I'll generate a raw query in Firefox SQLite Manager:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item WHERE (arg1=40 OR arg2=42) AND arg3=false
```

I'll get the error: "no such column: false"
If I generate a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item WHERE (arg1=40 OR arg2=42) AND arg3="false"
```

It'll not fail. BUT. I'm using selectionargs. I've read, that they should AVOID this situation. But they don't. Even, If I put into the selectionargs for arg3 = "\"+"false"+"\"" or arg3 = "\'+"false"+"\'" or even arg3="'"+"false"+"'" it won't work. Maybe an android specific problem? 
The value "false" comes from a list of values. It is initialized with an emty string.

Query-Method looks like this:

```
public List<Map<String,String>> getSearchResults(String sqlWhere, String[]args)
    {
        List<Map<String,String>> specs = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();
        String[] specnames = this.getSpecNames();

        Cursor cursor = mDb.query(dbSchema.SpecSchema.TABLE_NAME, specnames, sqlWhere, args, null, null, dbSchema.SpecSchema._ID + dbSchema.SORT_ASC);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast())
        {
            Map<String, String> temp = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for(int i = 0; i < specnames.length; i++)
                temp.put(specnames[i], cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(specnames[i])));
            specs.add(temp);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        if(cursor != null)
            cursor.close();

        return specs;
    }
```

Comment: Do you call your method like `getSearchResults("(arg1=? OR arg2=?) AND arg3=?", new String[]{"40", "42", "false"});`?

Comment: @bieglux: I was terribly wrong. The queryWhere String and the args had a mismatch. queryWhere has another behavior. Adding only arg1 will have the desired result. Adding arg2 will fail. This is, if arg1 is added, the function call might look like this: `getSearchResults("arg1=?", new String[]{"false"});`. if i add arg2, the function call will be `getSearchResults("(arg1=?) AND arg2=?", new String[]{"false", "40"});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`SQLiteDatabase.query()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says:

> *selectionArgs* - You may include ?s in selection, which will be replaced by the values from selectionArgs, in order that they appear
>   in the selection. **The values will be bound as Strings.**

When you execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE (arg1=40 OR arg2=42) AND arg3=false
```

and bind the arguments using the `selectionArgs`-parameter, the integers and the boolean will be bound as strings. This is not the same as in your database. I know you said all your columns are of type `TEXT`, but read the [SQLite Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity):

> The type affinity of a column is **the recommended type for data stored
>   in that column.** The important idea here is that **the type is
>   recommended, not required. Any column can still store any type of
>   data.** It is just that some columns, given the choice, will prefer to
>   use one storage class over another.

That means, when you insert your integer values in your string-table, SQLite will convert those and store them as integers. The next important point is [comparison](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#expraff):

> SQLite may attempt to **convert values between the storage classes**
>   INTEGER, REAL, and/or TEXT before performing a comparison.
>   [...]
>
> - An expression that is a simple reference to a column value has **the same affinity as the column**.

The docs give the following example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1(
    a TEXT,      -- text affinity
    b NUMERIC,   -- numeric affinity
    c BLOB,      -- no affinity
    d            -- no affinity
);

-- Because column "a" has text affinity, numeric values on the
-- right-hand side of the comparisons are converted to text before
-- the comparison occurs.
SELECT a < 40,   a < 60,   a < 600 FROM t1;
0|1|1
```

In your case that means the following:

1. Your `TEXT`-table gets integers inserted, which are then converted (and stored) as `INTEGER`s.
2. When performing your comparison, you give in `TEXT`-values (which are your integers). Those should be (but don't need to be) converted to `TEXT`-values, because your table indicates it's values are of type `TEXT`.
3. You compare `INTEGER` to `TEXT`, which is not equal and therefor doesn't give you the correct results.

---

To insert different data-types (other then string) into the SQLiteDatabase, use [Prepared Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android).

Comment: The Test Queries are send from the Firefox Extension "SQlite Manager" I have Strings (arg3 is VARCHAR(5)) in that Database AND I request Strings from the Database. I found the error, that arg1 and arg2 are Integers, but I pass Strings. Bizarrely if I create a Query with only arg1 and arg2 as Strings, it'll succeed. If I add arg3 as String, it'll fail.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `SQLiteDatabase` methods intead.

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE (arg1=40 OR arg2=42) AND arg3=false
```

should be

```
SQLiteDatabase db;
String table = "item";
String projection = null;
String selection = "(arg1=? OR arg2=?) AND arg3=?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[] { "40", "42", "false" };
String sortOrder = null;

db.query(item, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
```

It's not as concise, but it's much safer in that it'll protect against SQL injections and is less likely to cause problems (such as SQL syntax errors, etc.).

Comment: Please have a look at my question. I am using it. Data is validated BEFORE passing into getSearchResults(String sqlWhere, String[]args)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, arg1 is the column name, it is not a variable name.  So, when you do the first query, you are looking for all rows where the column named arg1=false.  In all the subsequent queries you add column arg2 and then column arg3, are there columns arg2 and arg3?  Can you post the code you used to create the table?