# Using int value in selection args argument of sqlite for android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Is this the correct way to convert an int into a string before use with Integer.toString()?   Is there another way to do this where conversion is not required?

Example:

```
 int value = 10;
 Cursor cursor = database.query(
    "TABLE_X", 
    new String[] { "COLUMN_A", "COLUMN_B" },
    "COLUMN_C = ?",
    new String[] { Integer.toString(value) },
    null,
    null,
    null);
```

Comment: Read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687724/android-sqlite-selection-args-incorrect-value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use the following ways to convert `int` to `String`.

```
int i=10;
String[] str = new String[]{String.valueOf(i)};
String[] str1 = new String[]{Integer.toString(i)};
```