# Update integer values in SQLite database (java)

Tags: java, android, sqlite, integer

I am pretty new to SQLite databases, so please forgive me...

I have a database with integer values. When updating a row in the database using the code below, there is somehting I don't understand. whereArgs is of type String[], though the values you are looking for are integers, so I would expect that one should pass in a int[].

```
    SQ.update(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs)
```

Where do I go wrong?

Example code (hypothetical):

```
public void changeOneIntoTwo(DatabaseOperations dop) {
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = dop.getWritableDatabase();
    String selection = "ValuesColumn = ?";
    String[] args = {"1"};
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put("ValuesColumn", 2);
    SQ.update("MyTable", cv, selection, args);
}
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't support ints as parameterised args. It should be safe just to do `selection = "ValuesColumn = " + Integer.toString(myNumber);`

Comment: Just pass the string array, sqlite will "know" if it's an int. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17481981/using-int-value-in-selection-args-argument-of-sqlite-for-android

Comment: in sql, string 1 and int 1 both are correctly represented as `'1'`. So no worries to have, the sql engine will know what type to expect for what column.

Comment: Java being so very precise, I am a bit disappointed that sqlite is all of a sudden interpreting strings as ints... But thanks, anyway!

Comment: @njzk2 This is wrong; the comparison will work only if the column has numeric [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

Comment: @CL. `column = ?` with `"1"` as an arg will work if that column as the value `1`, no matter its type.

Comment: @njzk2 No [it does not](http://sqliteonline.com/#fiddle-56273c3120fc23c787051fa9a2a98125438b690761ecf68968).

Comment: @CL. I am skeptical. what you are showing is different. `column = ? with "1"` is expanded at some point into an actual query. I have used that in various projects, and it works. Plus, with the android sql api, there is no way of passing anything but strings as parameters to the query. (unless you build your query yourself, but what would be the point?)

Comment: @njzk2 As I said, it works if the column has numeric affinity. In that fiddle, it has not.

Comment: @CL. I don't know how to see what type the column is in your fiddle

Comment: @njzk2 right-click; "SQL Schema". Anyway, here's an [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/da2f8/1) (it was broken this morning).

Comment: @CL. thanks, that's quite interesting. I created a table with various columns of various types (yours has no type at all), and all select yield the same result with or without `'`. Has `TEXT` numeric affinity?

Comment: @njzk2 TEXT has TEXT [affinity](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity).

Comment: @CL. but then why does `create table t(x TEXT); insert into t (1); insert into t ('1'); select * from t where x = '1';  select * from t where x = 1;` both return the 2 lines? (same for other column type, at least int, numeric and varchar).

Comment: @njzk2 See section 3 of the documentation I linked to.

Comment: @CL. Ok. But then, in your example, the right-hand operand always has an affinity (`'1'` -> TEXT or `1` -> NUMERIC), which should be passed to the left-hand operand since the column has no affinity. Once the expression has either TEXT or NUMERIC affinity, the comparison should always be true (`'1' = 1` and `1 = '1'`). But your example demonstrate that it is not the case. Why?

Comment: @njzk2 Plain expressions have no affinity.

Comment: @CL. not the expression itself, but the right-hand operand should give its affinity to the left-hand (since the right hand operator has either TEXT or NUMERIC affinity)

Comment: @njzk2 The right hand operator has no affinity (see section 3.2).

Comment: @CL. I don't see why. isn't `'1'` a text?

Comment: @njzk2 Only values from table columns have an affinity; plan expressions have just a type.

Comment: @CL. makes sense now. So the thing I get out of all this is mainly to give columns a type so they get affinity too, so the value can be converted when relevant. (and that column type and value type in the column are possible different). Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain.

Answer (score -1):

selection is the condition that you put in where clause of Sql query and args is  what replaced by "?" of selection .

for example : lets assume you need your sql query   select * from Mytable where ValuesColumn ='1' and Name = 'MVB'.  so in this case

> String selection = "ValuesColumn = ?  AND Name = ?";
>
> String[] args = {"1","MVB"};