# sqlite update multiple columns with Values List

Tags: list, sqlite, set

i have a simple table named "test" in an sqlite DB

columns: id, foo, bar
row1: 1, 5 , 6
row2: 2, 7 , 8

I want to update the rows with the following sqlite statement:

> UPDATE test SET (foo, bar) = ( 8, 9 )

according to https://sqlite.org/lang_update.html and the picture there it should be possible. It is also recommended in [UPDATE syntax in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482091/update-syntax-in-sqlite)

Unfortunately i get

> near "(": syntax error:

A Syntax like:

> UPDATE test SET foo=8, bar=9

works, but is not the solution here.

Can somebody explain why the list query is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Update: I have tried with an online query builder where this is actually working. So the issue must be with sqlite3 for python

Comment: >>> sqlite3.version
'2.6.0'  
>>> sqlite3.sqlite_version
'3.14.2'

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with the sqlite3 Version in Python (even latest version) has dll with sqlite3.sqlite_version = 3.14

Feature became available with sqlite 3.15...