# inserting text in database how to take care of '

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

Hi I am inserting general comments in to my database dynamically. and my query looks like this:

```
String sql = "insert into table (comment) values('"+ dynamic_comment + "');";
```

I am getting an error when a use insert something like this:

> I'm doing great

becuase at that time my query becomes:

```
insert into table (comment) values('I'm doing great');
```

***'I'm doing great'***

```
Error: Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "t": 
syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: 
insert into timeline(comment) values('Can't belive it really works');
```

Can someone tell me how to overcome this problem and how many other problems I can face like this while working with database.

thanks

Comment: You're not the first person to encounter this issue.  Did you try searching for the answer?

Comment: Use [**parameters**](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Parameters.html).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use prepared statements, concatenating raw strings into queries has been bad practice for a very long time now.

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("insert into table (comment) values(?)");
stmt.bindString(1, dynamic_comment);
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: why did you put 1 here: stmt.bindString(1, dynamic_comment);

Comment: Take a look at [the javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteProgram.html#bindString(int,%20java.lang.String)) - I am binding the first parameter (the `?`) to the value of `dynamic_comment`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape your string variable before insertion.

```
String sql = "insert into table (comment) values('"+ DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(dynamic_comment) + "');";
```

---

The above method is prone to SQL inject attacks. To be on the safer side, learn more about using [parametric statements](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/docs/Parameters.html).

A sample for the same query as yours will be:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement("INSERT INTO `table` (`comment`) values(?)");
stmt.bindString( 1, dynamic_comment );
stmt.execute();
```

Comment: Always use parameterised statements, other wise you're just asking for SQL injection attacks.

Comment: hmm, Didn't know about prepared statements in sqlite/android too. Thanks. Editing reply now @pablochan

Comment: dint help at all, inserting abcd and getting result as 'abcd'.