# Android - Make String SQL Safe

Tags: android, sql, string

My CO-worker has created the below code for iOS to make a user defined string SQL search safe. 
i.e to remove the possibility of SQL-injections and that kind of thing

```
char * sqlSafeQuery = sqlite3_mprintf("%q",[searchTerm UTF8String]);

searchTerm = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", sqlSafeQuery];

sqlite3_free(sqlSafeQuery);
```

Is there a way in android to so something similar? I can't see much on the Google's :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement), see [an Android question on how to use these in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android). As the statement is parsed without the user input in it, the parameters cannot change the statement itself; thus the injection cannot happen.

Comment: Prepared statements can not be used for queries which return a cursor, which is where i need to use it. thanks for your suggestion

Comment: In android you should use [one of the query methods](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29), they return a cursor and support prepared-statement-like syntax (question marks within `selection` get replaced with values from `selectionArgs`).

Comment: This i already do, however I do not think this combat things like SQl injections, escape characters and wildcard characters, this is what I am worried about.

Comment: The [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html#Injection) claims that they use prepared statements for this type of query, and that the query is injection safe for `selectionArgs`. Arguments within the `selection` itself are *not* injection safe.