# Why does the RoomDatabase.Callback method onCreate provide a SupportSQLiteDatabase parameter?

Tags: android, android-room

DISCLAIMER: This is not a "please fix my broken app" question. I'm not looking for a solution or a workaround. In fact, I've already [provided one myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63304318/1785730). This question is about why the API was designed this way.

```
roomDB = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "my-db")
        .addCallback(new RoomDatabase.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                super.onCreate(db);
                roomDB.getDao().insert(someEntity);
            }
        })
        .build();
```

This code leads straight into an Exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: getDatabase called recursively

Why? Because the `onCreate` callback already provides a database instance in its parameter and the line `roomDB.getDao().insert(someEntity);` is somehow trying to get another. The consequence of `onCreate` providing a database instance is that the database cannot be accessed with the abstractions Room provides, but only directly. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite) even warns about not to work with the SQLiteDatabase directly.

I have to say this again: The very first time, when I want to access my shiny new Room database, I'm forced to work with the low level SQLiteDatabase instead because of the design of the API.

My question is: Why? Is this a bug in the API design? Or are there legitimate use cases, where accessing the SQLiteDatabase directly is preferable?

If there was no SupportSQLiteDatabase instance in the parameters to `onCreate`, I would expect this code to work fine:

```
roomDB = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "my-db")
        .addCallback(new RoomDatabase.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                roomDB.getDao().insert(someEntity);
            }
        })
        .build();
```

**EDIT:** The database is ready, when the `onCreate` callback is invoked:

```
db = Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "my-db")
        .addCallback(new RoomDatabase.Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
                super.onCreate(db);
                Log.d("DB", "onCreate called");
            }
        })
        .build();

Log.d("DB", "database ready");
```

Because control flow already moved past the setup of the database, when the `onCreate` callback is invoked:

```
D/DB: database ready
...
D/DB: onCreate called
```

Comment: Questions of the form "why did Developer X make Decision Y?" are usually not good for Stack Overflow. Frequently, only Developer X can answer, and that is statistically unlikely to occur. Anyone else can only offer guesses.

Comment: I would agree if the question was about some obscure library nobody ever heard of. But I do not think this applys to Android. And I'm open to the possibility that I'm missing something and there are use cases where one might need the SQLiteDatabase instance provided.

Comment: "But I do not think this applys to Android" -- there are still only a handful of Google engineers who would have been involved in the decision. "I'm open to the possibility that I'm missing something" -- well, for one, you are assuming that the DAOs would work at this point in the database-creation process. That may or may not be correct. The developer may need to execute some PRAGMAs or otherwise prep the database before the DAOs will work. So, if I had to guess, they went this route for safety's sake.

Comment: I was hoping that the design of the Android API is not the secret knowledge of a handful of Google engineers. As for the other concern, I would argue that the database is ready when `onCreate` is invoked. I've updated my question to show why.

Comment: "I've updated my question to show why" -- you have shown that the work is done [lazily](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation).