# How to avoid special characters SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm facing an issue with SQLite in Android, I know the solution must be simple, but what I have done is not working !!

```
 // Update a contact with a new name
    public void updatename (String phone, String newname) {
        newname = newname.replaceAll("'","\'");
        String query = "UPDATE contacts SET name = '"+newname+"' WHERE phone = '"+phone+"'";
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.execSQL(query);

        //db.close();


    }
```

the replace function is not working !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PreparedStatement, and should never do the quoting stuff yourself, just unnecessary trouble:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("UPDATE constacts SET name = ? WHERE phone = ?");
pstmt.setString(1, "foo")
pstmt.setString(2, '123")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [update()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) to map your strings into placeholders, and Sqlite will escape the strings so that the final command is always valid.

You should always be doing this for every command.

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not use a backslash for escaping.
In SQL string literals, quotes are doubled, so you'd need to replace `'` with `''`.

But it would be a better idea to use parameters:

```java
    String query = "UPDATE contacts SET name = ? WHERE phone = ?";
    db.execSQL(query, new Object[]{ newname, phone });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Prepared Statements. This sanitizes the input for you before calling the sql command.

[How do I use prepared statements in SQlite in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android)