# Fatal - RuntimeException SQLite Remove Data from Database

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause, runtimeexception

I am trying to delete data from SQLite table where source column equals to "Online"

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.reminders/com.reminders.FetchDataActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Online (code 1): , while compiling: delete from ReminderTable where source = Online
```

Here is my code:

```
public void deleteOnlineReminders() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_REMINDERS + " where " + KEY_SOURCE + " = " + "Online");
    }
```

`Or` Is it due to reason that I don't have any data into table where column source = Online

Comment: Before doing this ,just check whether table is created or not,the exception seems there is no column named KEY_SOURCE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code.**

```
db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_REMINDERS + " where " + KEY_SOURCE + "=?",new String[] { "Online" });
```

Comment: now getting : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.reminders/com.reminders.FetchDataActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: delete from ReminderTable where source =

Comment: @Sun I have just edited only added `Question Mark After Equal to` try and check.

Comment: simply thank you... why we have used Question mark after equals to

Comment: @Sun It is used to pass field value which you have given in where condition. that's it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use 'Online' in your string concat (note the quotes).

As you can see from the exception, the compiled statement is otherwise wrong as you are refering to a column, not a string.

You may also want to use prepared statements instead of string concatenation for your parameter:
[How do I use prepared statements in SQlite in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android)

This is the more clean and safe version :)

Comment: I tried this way too : db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_REMINDERS + " where " + KEY_SOURCE + " = Online"); but still getting same exception

Comment: db.execSQL("delete from "+ TABLE_REMINDERS + " where " + KEY_SOURCE + " = 'Online'"

Note the additional single Quotes around Online

Answer (score 0):

```
public void deleteOnlineReminders() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();       
    dbHelper.delete(TABLE_REMINDERS, KEY_SOURCE + "=?", new String[] { Online})
}
```