# my command to sum up the price values isnt working

Tags: android

public ArrayList calculateTotal() {

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ArrayList<Integer> array_list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(
            "SELECT SUM(cost) FROM expense", null);
    if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
        columntotal = cursor1.getFloat(0);
    }
    cursor1.close();
    db.rawQuery("INSERT INTO total VALUES(columntotal)", null);
```

I'm unable to sum up the cost and display in android studio....

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an exception?

Answer (score 0):

Your insert command should be something like below:

```
"INSERT INTO total VALUES("+columntotal+")"
```

Its better to use [PreparadStatement approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android)