# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "": syntax error (code 1): error while reading from database by matching two differ keywords

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to get/read data by matching an Integer ID and a specific String, But while compiling the code I am getting this error :

```
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Computing": syntax
> error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM midSemAnsBank WHERE
> id = 4 AND subject = Cloud Computing
```

Here's what I'm trying :

```
    openReadable();
    String select_query= "SELECT * FROM " +MID_SEM_ANSWERS_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_ID + " = " + answerID +" AND " + KEY_SUBJECT + " = " + subject +" " ;
    Log.d(LOG, select_query);
    Cursor c= m_sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(select_query,null);
    if(c!=null)
        c.moveToFirst();
```

what's the proper query to read data by matching two keywords?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String should be between two `''` so instead :

```
String select_query= "SELECT * FROM " +MID_SEM_ANSWERS_TABLE + " WHERE " + 
     KEY_ID + " = " + answerID +" AND " + KEY_SUBJECT + " = '" + subject + "'";
//----------------------------------------------------------^---------------^
```

---

**Note**

The important thing, your code still not secure, and can cause Syntax error or **SQL Injection**, i suggest to use PreparedStatement instead, read also more about [How do I use prepared statements in SQlite in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android).