# What is causing the errors in the following java code

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have implemented a method to validate a user against an SQLite DB but the program keeps throwing an error when the login button is clicked  the error codes follow

> 2019-04-15 21:38:27.455 4601-4601/com.example.mymedicare
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.mymedicare, PID: 4601
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Brad (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM users WHERE Brad =? AND
>   Brad1994 =?
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native
>   Method)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1318)
>           at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1257)
>           at com.example.mymedicare.MyDBHelper.checkLogin(MyDBHelper.java:96)

I have tried reading the error log but can't find any serious errors my methods will be shown below

```
  // This is my check login method in mydbhelper   

   public boolean checkLogin(String username, String password) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    String s;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE " + username + " =? AND " + password + " =?", null);

    if (c.getCount() <= 0) {
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return false;
    } else {
        c.close();
        db.close();
        return true;
    }
}


   //This is LoggingIn activity where I have tried to implement the above 
   method 

   public class LoggingIn extends AppCompatActivity {

//defines page objects
private Button SignIn;
private EditText Usernames;
private EditText Passwords;
private MyDBHelper db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_logging_in);

    //Finds objects by ID
     //edit text to string
    Usernames = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Usernames);

    Passwords = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Passwords);


    Button SignIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SignIn);
    db = new MyDBHelper(this);

    SignIn.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Boolean validUser = 
     db.checkLogin(Usernames.getText().toString(), 
     Passwords.getText().toString());

            if (validUser == true) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
                HomePage.class);
                startActivity(i);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid login", 
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: The SQL you're constructing is bad.  It's trying to execute SQL that literally says, `SELECT * FROM users WHERE Brad =? AND Brad1994 =?`, which isn't valid.  Double-check how you're building the SQL.  Your variables need to replace the question marks, not be inserted in place of the column names.

Comment: I assume your table has columns called `Brad` and `Brad1994`?

Comment: Hi no the table has username password, age, address etc. That error comes up when I try to log in brad and brad1994 are usernames and passwords respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the parameters `username` and `password` as column names. 
The correct way is:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT * FROM users WHERE usenamecolumn = ? AND passwordcolumn = ?", 
     new String[] {username, password});
```

Change `usenamecolumn` and `passwordcolumn` to your table's column names for username and password.

Comment: Thanks I will try this when I get back and let you know the outcome !

Comment: Thanks for all the input everybody really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something closer to this:

```
    db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?", null);
```

In the way you've written it above you're attempting to perform a query using the search criteria (value) as the column name (key).

E.g. in plain English the first part of your original statement says "find something in column Brad" which is why your exception is popping up with "SQLiteException: no such column: Brad"

What you actually wanted to say was "find Brad in column username", which is what the revised statement I've added above should do for you (it's untested but on the right track to get you going).

I found this other StackOverflow post which might help in creating prepared statements as well -> [How do I use prepared statements in SQlite in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433392/how-do-i-use-prepared-statements-in-sqlite-in-android)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is close but every time I push login with this code it says invalid login regardless if the details are in the db or not not sure what to do next

Comment: Just looking at the docs (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase), rawQuery has two constructors, one with a CancellationSignal object as its third parameter, which you've specified as "null" above, and one which does not have this third parameter. Have you tried removing the third constructor param from your rawQuery command? Also, try adding a break point at the line where you substantiate "Cursor c" and debugging the result of that, this might give you more to troubleshoot.